# Angular2 Input/Output in formControl instead ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope, angular2-forms

I have a calender directive where I am passing date and want it to update parent component's date too. Its working good with ngModel but when trying with formControl, its not updating parent's component data.
Below is code snippet:

```
// Model value is updating:
<input [(ngModel)]="data" />
<calender [(currentDate)]="currentDate"  ></calender>

//  FormControl value is not updating:
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input formControlName="date" />
<calender [(currentDate)]="myForm.controls.date.value"  ></calender>`
</form>
```

Calender Component's code snippet:

```
@Input() currentDate:string;
@Output() currentDateChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
updateOutput(){ this.currentDate="someDate" this.currentDateChange.emit(this.currentDate); }
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code for Calendar but I think maybe you are not implementing ControlValueAccessor interface. This article is good for creating custom controls: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: try using [(formGroup)] binding on <form> element

Comment: In the parent template, try accessing the field value with `myForm.get('date').value`. Also, when you switched to the new syntax, did you think of importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your module and did you create the form model in your component class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the output. The Input will keep the parent date up to date if you update it with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: [(ngModel)] code is working good but when using formControl, its not updating formControl value